# popup window javascript (how to add focus to popup window)

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

How to add focus to popup window in this code please help me someone.

```
 <script>

$(document).ready(function() {  

    //select all the a tag with name equal to modal
    $('a[name=modal]').click(function(e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();

        //Get the A tag
        var id = $(this).attr('href');

        //Get the screen height and width
        var maskHeight = $(document).height();
        var maskWidth = $(window).width();

        //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
        $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

        //transition effect     
        $('#mask').fadeIn(10);  
        $('#mask').fadeTo("fast",0.8);  

        //Get the window height and width
        var winH = $(window).height();
        var winW = $(window).width();


        //Set the popup window to center
        $(id).css('top',  winH/8-$(id).height()/2);
        $(id).css('left', winW/2.5-$(id).width()/2);

        //transition effect
        $(id).fadeIn(100); 

    });

    //if close button is clicked
    $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#mask').hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });     

    //if mask is clicked
    $('#mask').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });         

});

</script>
```

Comment: Where do you create the popup window? I don't see window.open().

Comment: Don't see any popup being created in the code.....

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with that you expect this line

```
var id = $(this).attr('href');
```

to give you the reference of a `window` or a `<div>`  (your code would almost make sense if it  was a div), and that the div was an overlay (not popup).

I think you need to find the code which creates the overlay, and then you can ".[show](http://api.jquery.com/show/)()" and ".[focus](http://api.jquery.com/focus/)()" on one of the fields inside the div.